# ASP.NET Getting float from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this method here which will get me a float from the database:

```
public List<AvidClass> getAvidByJob(string customerID)
        {
            AvidCell = new List<AvidClass>();

            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT construction, moveIn, yearEnd FROM AvidRating WHERE CustomerID = '" + customerID + "'");
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                AvidClass item = new AvidClass();

                item.construction = (float)dataReader[0];
                item.moveIn = (float)dataReader[1];
                item.yearEnd = (float)dataReader[2];

                AvidCell.Add(item);

            }
            connection.Close();

            return AvidCell;
        }
```

but I get this error:

```
 Specified cast is not valid.
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Here is my class

```
public class AvidClass
    {
        public string community { get; set; }
        public string lot { get; set; }
        public int customerid { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public float construction { get; set; }
        public float moveIn { get; set; }
        public float yearEnd { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Check the type that is getting returned from the SqlCommand then we can decide how to convert it.

Comment: What are underlying data type and actual data of construction, moveIn and yearEnd in SQL Db? Could you post the sample? In addition, you want to use **parameterized query** to prevent [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
Float.Parse(DataReader[0].toString());
```

Just try out the different suggestions of your IDE and you'll get the right one.

Comment: I get this error: `'Float' does not exist in current context'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using getfloat
item.construction = reader.GetFloat(reader.GetOrdinal("0"));